# Show image dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using http request to get the path of image from database and images are located in the server.

I want to show that image in img src.

Here is the code:

```
  $http({
    url     : 'user_profile_exec.php',
      method: "GET",
      params: {uid: user_id}
    })
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.fname = data.cv_fname;
      $scope.lname = data.cv_lname;
      $scope.pic = data.pic;
      alert($scope.pic);
    }
  });
```

It is showing the data in network tab also data is showing in alert box.

Here is the body code:

```
<div id="errors" class="kari" style="display: center" ng-style="{'display':$scope.pic == ''?'none':'block'}">
<img src="./img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive " />
    {{pic}}
</div>

<div id="errors" class="kari" style="display: center" ng-style="{'display':$scope.pic != ''?'none':'block'}">
    <img src="{{pic}}" class="img-responsive " />
</div>
```

Unfortunately 2.jpg is showing, however I am expecting the output of image path that is stored in database.

I also tried like below, but I am getting error `pic` is not defined.

```
<div id="errors" class="kari" style="display: center" ng-style="{'display':pic == ''?'none':'block'}">
<img src="./img/2.jpg" class="img-responsive " />
    {{pic}}
</div>

<div id="errors" class="kari" style="display: center" ng-style="{'display':pic != ''?'none':'block'}">
    <img src="{{pic}}" class="img-responsive " />
    {{fname}}
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use ng-src instead of src,

```
<img ng-src="{{pic}}" class="img-responsive " />
  {{fname}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am not sure what to use here ng-style="{'display':$scope.pic == ''?'none':'block'} or ng-style="{'display':pic == ''?'none':'block'} which one i should use? voted up.

Comment: ng-style="{'display':pic == ''?'none':'block'}

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Just to show/hide your elements you can use [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)/[`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)/[`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directives.

Comment: <img src="./img/2.jpg" - make sure this src must get actuall path.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash well i am not sure i can use ngShow/ngHide in this case or not as i have to make sure data is there or not. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Well both answers are correct. i used ng-if and later i will explore ng-show/hide. searching SO.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine I think in your case you can make it work even without 2 different div elements. Something like `<div id="errors" class="kari" style="display: center">
<img ng-src="{{pic ? pic : './img/2.jpg'}}" class="img-responsive " />
{{fname ? fname: '2.jpg'}}
</div>` should work, since you can use expressions inside interpolation braces.  Was writing an answer, but noticed you've already accepted this variant :)

Comment: @StanislavKvitash if you write the answer then i would be very grateful. At least if will help me before asking another question.

Answer (score 2):

Change src to  ng-src

```
<img ng-src="{{pic}}" class="img-responsive " />
  {{fname}}
</div>
```

Also define $scope.pic=""; in the controller to overcome this undefined issue.
Hope this will also help..

Comment: controller is defined in the begining of body tag. if i want to show fname or lname then it is showing but only facing issue with pic.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Well both answers are correct. i used ng-if and later i will explore ng-show/hide. searching SO. voted up.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have the same `div` element (even with same `id="errors"`), but you want to toggle image inside this element.

To achieve this you can use [`ngSrc`directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) together with [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) to set the src attribute of your image. Example:

```js
function TestControler($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.pic = '';

  //testing different urls
  $scope.togglePick = function (pic){
    if (!$scope.pic){
      $scope.pic = $scope.fname = "//www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg";
    } else {
      $scope.pic = $scope.fname = '';
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.testBtn {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.kari {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TestControler">

<button ng-click="togglePick()" class="testBtn">
Toggle pic
</button>


<div id="errors" class="kari">
  <img ng-src="{{pic ? pic : './img/2.jpg'}}" class="img-responsive " /> 
  {{fname ? fname : '2.jpg'}}
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

BTW, `center` is not a valid value for the [`display` property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Comment: Glad to help, hope this will be useful for you!