# How can I show an image when its fully loaded as Base64?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have the following code line using Ionic3:

```
<ion-img src="data:image/bmp;base64,{{poline.itemimagedata}}">
```

In `{{poline.itemimagedata}}`, a `base64 image` is contained.

The problem is: To the time of the views loading, the variable might not be filled but can later be filled or updated. Ionic fails to update the image accordingly in this case. Is there a nice solution to this?

Do I have to manually update the image when the variable has been filled? If so, how? Maybe there's even an option for a nice loading indicator within the img?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No. It just loads a blank image if the variable is not loaded (and the image if it is filled with something) and does't update to the new image when I load a new image into the variable.
(I guess this is the intended behavior, im just looking for the correct way to solve my problem.)

Comment: Use [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive instead of `src` attribute. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44507003/4222181).

Comment: Disregard my first comment, haven't noticed you are using `ion-img`. Is `poline.itemimagedata` well formed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "well formed"? Its a variable of type ANY. It works when I reload the view or when the variable is already filled when the view is loaded. But it doesn't update it live.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. Can you try to use `src="{{'data:image/bmp;base64,' + poline.itemimagedata}}"` or `[src]="'data:image/bmp;base64,' + poline.itemimagedata"` and see if it helps?

Comment: Hey, both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by manually triggering the change detection:

ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();